# Using Angular ng-repeat to create nested list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to create a list of layers and nested list of sublayers for each layer by iterating this object with ng-repeat.

```
var lyrslist = [
    { layername: "Base Maps", layertype: "layer" },
    { layername: "Open Street Map", layertype: "sublayer" },
    { layername: "Designated Sites", layertype: "layer" },
    { layername: "Ancient Woodlands", layertype: "sublayer" },
    { layername: "Conservation Areas", layertype: "sublayer" },
    { layername: "Listed Buildings", layertype: "sublayer" }
];
```

#### HTML

```
<h5>Layers</h5>
<ul ng-repeat="lyr in lyrslist">
  <li ng-if="lyr.layertype === 'layer'" >
    Layer {{lyr.layername}}
    <ul>
      <li ng-if="lyr.layertype === 'sublayer'"> 
       Sub Layer {{lyr.layername}}
     </li>
   </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

The result is that only the Layers are being listed. It seems that `ng-repeat` doesn't cascade down to the next `<ul>`. I tried putting `ng-repeat` inside the `<ul>` tag but that just the whole list instead of the just the required sub-layers.

This is the result I'm trying to get:

```
Layers
- Layer Base Maps
    - Sub Layer Open Street Map

- Layer Designated Sites
    - Sub Layer Ancient Woodlands
    - Sub Layer Conservation Areas
    - Sub Layer Listed Buildings
```

Comment: check my answer

Comment: You have to remake your list because it should look like:

`[{ layername:"Base Maps",  layertype:"layer", sublayer: [layername:"Open Street Map",  layertype:"sublayer"]}]`. Then you can easily generate view easily.
Check my answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I think you are looking for this:**

> You have to redesign your object for better output. I have include
>   sublayer inside layer. That's why you can easily display sub layer in
>   view.

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[])
app.controller('ctrl',function($scope){
var lyrslist = [{ layername:"Base Maps",  layertype:"layer"},  {layername:"Open Street Map",  layertype:"sublayer"}, { layername:"Designated Sites",  layertype:"layer"}, { layername:"Ancient Woodlands",  layertype:"sublayer"}, { layername:"Conservation Areas",  layertype:"sublayer"}, { layername:"Listed Buildings",  layertype:"sublayer"}];

var newList = []; var count = 0; 
angular.forEach(lyrslist, function(value, key) {
 if(value.layertype=='layer'){
    this.push(value);
    this[count].sub = []; //define sub layer inside layer
    count++;
   }else{
    this[count-1].sub.push(value); //assign sub layer inside layer
   }
}, newList);
//console.log(newList);
$scope.lyrslist = newList;
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="lyr in lyrslist">
                Layer: {{lyr.layername}}
              <ul>
                  <li ng-repeat="sublyr in lyr.sub"> 
                     SubLayer: {{sublyr.layername}}
                 </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh sorry @Robert, Layer name was not appear because of my little mistake. Check it now.

Comment: @AHJeebon That's an awesome solution !! Recreating new array list. it would be easier if array list has sublayer as another property:)

Comment: @AHJeebon I agree, that's awesome. Thanks!